# Django: Access model through another model

Tags: django, model

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()  

class Job(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
```

I have many jobs for each project. How do i get a list of all users of all jobs of a project?
I came up with this:

```
users = set()
for job in project.job_set.all():
    users.add(job.user)
```

Is there an easier way without explicitely looping through every job?

Comment: You could also have written `users = set(job.user for job in project.job_set.all())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Django's join syntax](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) and start from your `User` model instead:

```
users = User.objects.filter(job_set__project=project).distinct()
```

Comment: this line doesn't seem to work - says 
Cannot resolve keyword 'job_set' into field. Choices are:

Comment: i figured that instead of job_set there should be job. Thanx it works!

Comment: Based on the code in your question, since you haven't specified a `related_name` in the `ForeignKey`, it should have defaulted to `job_set`.  If you do this instead: `user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='jobs')`, then you would filter based on `jobs__project=project`

Comment: it's interesting because i havent specified a related name and it still goes by the name of the model and not the name of the field. I tried it on other models too. Maybe it's becuase im using alpha version of django

Comment: Very strange. I'd be careful since it disagrees with the documentation.  It could be a bug, but I don't know how that one could have slipped past their unit tests. 

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use a ManyToMany relation from Project to User through the Job model which is in effect a join model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
   users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Job')
   ...
```

And then simply do:

```
project.users.all()
```